# Folder redirection not working on workstation OS reinstall

Tags: folder-redirection, essentials-2012

One of our WSE 2012 domain-joined laptop workstations was having some trouble, so instead of spending time to troubleshoot it we decided that I'd wipe it and install Windows anew. I installed Win8 and then updated to 8.1 before joining the machine to the domain.

Before joining, I went into AD on the server and deleted the old entry.

For some reason, now that it's joined, folder redirection isn't working for any domain user profile created on this machine (it's working at all other stations). I can manually edit the shell folders to point to the network shares without any trouble, but automatic redirection at profile creation isn't occurring.

Drive mapping is working fine.

How to track this down?

Comment: I think this will do the trick for you,
http://richardjgreen.net/windows-server-2012-essentials-folder-redirection-windows-8-1/

Comment: @ddddd: I haven't tried it yet, but that sure looks like the trick. Goodness, how did you manage to find that?